# Jquery - select array set with dynamic name

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have n number of array sets as follows:

```
var array1 = [“1”,”2”,”3”];
var array2 = [“9”,”6”,”7”];
```

I need to select array set randomly to apply in a svg parameter.

```
//this fill will be random, as i need a random array set name to use for svg fill.

    random_fill = array2[0];
```

***Note:*** i’m particular about following above array structure as it will have a theme based colors.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could take all array in another array and get a random value of it.

```js
 var array1 = [1, 2, 3],
     array2 = [9, 6, 7],
     allArrays = [array1, array2],
     randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * allArrays.length),
     randomPick = allArrays[randomIndex];

console.log(randomPick);
```

Comment: As i mentioned, each array set is a theme. So, once i select a random theme, i want to choose only one random value of that one random array set. Could you please help me with that.

Basically the steps are: 1. Choose a random array set, 2. Select random values from that random array set.

Comment: you could take the same approach for choosing a value from `randomPick` with `index = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomPick.length)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Finally i could solve that by this code. (After many hours, i found the problem was, variables were not in global scope but inside jquery function. Added this solution to the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
//first put all the variables outside jquery function

//flat color palette
var total_palette = 2;
var palette_1 = ["#FFEFFF","#100E17","#463859","#695E79"];
var palette_2 = ["#FFF3F7","#924060","#DF87AA","#3F0E25"];

//randomize palette
var randnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (total_palette - 1 + 1) + 1);
var selected_palette = "palette_"+randnum;

//this line solved the issue
var svg_color = (window[selected_palette][3]);
```